# Create dataframe for correlations between different variables and by groups

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, correlation

I need a dataframe where correlations between a fix and a changing variable, divided by subgroups, are listed. 
The closest solution I've come up with is listed below, using the dataset mtcars as an example (correlations don't have to make sense).

```
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)
df <- load(mtcars)

as.factor(mtcars$am)
as.factor(mtcars$gear)
as.factor(mtcars$carb)

library(plyr)
cors <- function(var, group) {
  corrl <- ddply(df, .(group), summarise, "corr" = cor(var, mpg, method = "spearman"))
}

dafr.var <- as.vector(c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat"))
args<- merge(as.character(c("am", "gear", "carb")), dafr.var)
args[,1:2]<- lapply(args[,1:2], as.character)
colnames(args) <- c("grouping", "variable")

cortable <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(args)){
  cortable<- rbind(cortable, cors(var = df[args[i,2]], group = df[args[i,1]]))
}
cortable
```

"Cortable" will be the final dataframe, which lists correlations by subgroups as they are listed in the intermediate step - dataframe "args".

Is my question clear? Does anyone know why this does not work, or what I could change in my code? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this help to get you what you are looking for?

```
df <- mtcars

df$make <- rownames(df)
df$make <- sapply(df$make, function(x) strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][1])

cors <- function(var, group) {
  require(plyr)
  corrl  <- ddply(df, group, function(x) cor(x[,var], x[,"mpg"], method = "spearman"))
  corrl$var <- var
  corrl$group <- group
  colnames(corrl) <- c("value", "corr", "var", "group")
  return(corrl)
}

dafr.var <- as.vector(c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat"))
args <- merge(as.character(c("am", "gear", "carb", "make")), dafr.var)
args[,1:2] <- lapply(args[,1:2], as.character)
colnames(args) <- c("grouping", "variable")


cortable <- data.frame(value = numeric(), corr = numeric(), var = character(), group = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(args)){
  cortable <- rbind(cortable, cors(var = args[i,2], group = args[i,1]))
}

cortable <- cortable[,c("var","group","value","corr")]

cortable
```

Comment: Thank you! The code doesn't result in an error, but somehow correlations are not different by subgroups (which they should be). `value       corr  var group
1      0 -0.9108013  cyl    am
2      1 -0.9108013  cyl    am
3      3 -0.9108013  cyl  gear
4      4 -0.9108013  cyl  gear`; correlations for cylinder&gear should be a different result than correlations for cylinder&am, do you know what I mean? Also, if subgroups of _am_ were _male_ and _female_ (instead of 0 and 1), then the value of _value_ should be "male" and "female". If you are confused,I can provide real data if needed @Matt

Comment: I've updated my answer with some changes that I believe should get what you are looking for.

Comment: This works great. Thank you tons! Just one more question: how do I get the true values into the _value_-column? if the group was "city" (as in my real data), the value should be a character as **Barcelona**, **London**, **Vienna**, etc. instead of 1, 2, 3, etc. Just changing `cortable <- data.frame(value = numeric(), corr = numeric(), var = character(), group = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` to `cortable <- data.frame(value = character(), corr = numeric(), var = character(), group = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`doesn't do it.

Comment: The value should be determined from each unique value within the grouping variable. To replicate this behavior I've updated my answer to include a new field with the `make` of each car, you should see that when the process runs the `value` column returns back the character string showing the make of the vehicle and it's correlation.

Comment: Perfect. That is on such a high level. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you wanted to make this a little more efficient, you could also replace the `cortable <- data.frame()` statement and the entire `for` loop, with this one line apply command `cortable <- do.call(rbind, apply(args, 1, function(x) cors(x[["variable"]], x[["grouping"]])))`

Comment: Thank you! This looks great.